# Why am I unable to draw cards in Magic 2014?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I play Magic 2014 - Duels of the Planeswalkers (DotP) on Steam. I understand all of the basics except for one thing! In a recent battle, my turn started and I did not draw a card. The game went directly to my End phase. My Main and Combat phases were skipped. This happened for five or more turns in a row!

Are there any cards in Magic 2014 DotP that stop a player from drawing cards, or skip a draw step? Are there any settings that could cause my Main and Combat phases to be skipped when my hand is empty? Is this a bug?

Comment: Uh... wait, what? I can't figure out what you're asking here. The way you draw a card in Magic is that you pick it up from the top of the deck and put it in your hand. Or are you asking about Duels of the Planeswalkers instead?

Comment: Please edit to clarify / add more details.

Comment: Ya, I was talking about Magic 2014 : Duels of Planewalkers (Android)......

Comment: @jamius19 Right, but... are you saying the game didn't let you draw a card for several consecutive turns in one game?

Comment: @Jefromi ...  yap..... I have 7 uptapped lands.... and I know I've got plenty of small and large costing creatures in my deck! But they just won't draw! Its useless to have many lands without any creature!

Comment: Could you send add a screenshot of what you're seeing at that point in the game? This sounds like a bug, but it might be that your opponent or you have played a card that's affecting your draw step (don't think there are any of these in DotP2014, but there might be).

Comment: In the edited form, this is a fair question - though I'm not 100% confident from your comments that this is what's actually happening, since you keep talking about how many lands you have.

Comment: @Jefromi, Who knows. The OP hasn't been cooperative. It could be he has two different questions? Anyway, what stands is a valid question even if it's not the one the OP meant to ask, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @deworde I wonder how useful a single screenshot would be in demonstrating that a phase was skipped. Two screenshots taken during two different turns would definitely demonstrate that a card was not drawn.

Answer (score 2):

At the start of your turn, you draw 1 card. In a two player game, the start player does not draw a card at the start of his first turn.

If a computer version of MTG did not let you draw a card at the start of each turn, then either there was some sort of bug, or it was a special mode that changes the normal rules of Magic.

Comment: yap....Its probably a bug.......I cant pull out a card even if I've got plenty of lands..... so many turns are wasted

Comment: @jamius19 What do you mean "even if I've got plenty of lands"? You seem to be misunderstanding something, but it's not clear what. How many lands you have has nothing to do with drawing a card at the start of your turn.

Comment: @jamius19 My best guess is that you're thinking that, as long as there's nothing you can play in your hand, you should be allowed to draw another card when you want, not just one per turn? In that case, you should definitely have specifically said so in your question, but I guess this answer does answer your question: it's not a bug, you get one draw per turn. Getting stuck with nothing to do happens sometimes, though building your deck well makes it less likely.

Comment: I know that I can draw one card per turn! Think as I've got 7 untapped lands.... This turn ends without any creature in my hand! My opponent summons creature(es) and attacks.... His turn ends..... My turn starts.... But as no card is drawn from the library, it directly goes to the End phase without Combat or Main....Then my turn end..... And this keeps happening so on for 5/6 turns or more! @Jefromi

Comment: @jamius19 If it's skipping your draw step that's a bug, unless there's some weird modified/scripted game mode in there (I haven't played Magic 2014). But I still don't see what you having lands has to do with it - you always draw one card, no matter what. In any case, the explanation you finally gave is what you should edit into your question.

Comment: @jamius19 The confusing part is that you keep mentioning that you have untapped lands... this piece of information is not related in any way to drawing cards, so I don't see how it relates to the question.

Comment: @jamius19 And it really makes it sound like you might mean you're drawing land when you *want* creatures, due to you being unlucky about how your deck is shuffled.